# Тире после вводных слов

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь тире после "в частности" или можно обойтись запятой?

Одна из актуальных тем, имеющих непосредственное отношение к нашей компании  как к поставщику приводной техники для автоматизации арматуры, — это унификация характеристик, в частности, габаритных размеров арматуры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нужно ли здесь тире после "в частности" или можно обойтись запятой?

Лучше обойтись и без тире, и без запятой.

См. http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach2/ :

> Если вводное слово стоит в начале обособленного оборота – запятые
>   ставятся перед вводным словом и после всего обособленного оборота.
>   После вводного слова запятая не ставится (иначе говоря, запятая,
>   которая должна была «закрывать» вводное слово, переносится в конец
>   обособленного оборота).
>
> *...Трава забвенья. Я тоже привык записывать свои мысли на чем
>   попало, **в частности на папиросных коробках.***

Comment: Точно! Забыла это правило.

Answer (score 0):

Насчет запятой после "в частности" вполне согласен с предыдущим ответом, но тире перед "это" необходимо, так как здесь подлежащее и сказуемое выражены существительными

Comment: виктор1799, постарайтесь обходиться без ссылок на предыдущие ответы. Здесь невозможно понять, какой ответ Вы имеете в виду, когда их много. Тем более это невозможно, когда приходится проверять т.н. "сомнительные ответы". Я вижу сейчас только вопрос - и ваш ответ. И должен принять решение, одобрять ли его. Зная вас, я, конечно, не буду тормозить, но все-таки, хотелось бы видеть всю вашу мысль в законченном виде.

Comment: виктор1799: "…тире перед "это" необходимо…" === Перед "это" -- нужно; но в вопросе-то речь шла не об этом тире.   Спрашивалось, нужно ли  **тире после "в частности"**:   

"…унификация характеристик, **в частности** (?) габаритных размеров арматуры".